# Secure or encrypt input/output from C program?

Tags: c, security, encryption, terminal

I'm a fairly new computer engineering student making a program in C to learn more over summer.

I do not know or understand anything about encryption apart from a simple implementation of Diffie-Hellman.

My program is just a terminal based only and completely offline. It needs to read in saved data from a file and write back to the file when it's done. I'd like to encrypt the I/O in the program.

It seems simple but Googling has me running in circles because I don't know enough to actually get anywhere. Are there any resources someone could point me to about encryption basics and making an offline program secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to learn about general techniques for working with encrypted input and output files, I would suggest implementing a *very* simple "encryption" algorithm such as XOR with a constant. For example, the following very simple function would work for both encryption and decryption:

```
void encrypt(char *data, size_t len)
{
    while (len--) {
        *data++ ^= 0xFF;
    }
}
```

To read an encrypted file, you read a block of data, decrypt it, and then work with it as you would normally. You would do the opposite for writing: Encrypt the data, then write it.

When working with encrypted files, you won't be able to use the C stdio functions such as `fgets()` or `fprintf()`, because you don't have a chance to encrypt/decrypt the data between those functions and the actual file I/O.

Comment: I'm aware of the very simple ciphers like the Caesar cipher and XORing bytes but I'd like to learn to use the industry standards. Conceptually, I understand the very basics of crypto like symmetric vs. asymmetric. I understand the math behind DH too but it's the overall ideas behind keeping applications secure that I don't understand. Are there any resources for secure systems instead of just specific algorithms?

Comment: The overall ideas of keeping applications secure are largely independent of your specific choice of encryption algorithm. That is why I suggested you could learn using a simple XOR, as that removes the extra complexity of using real encryption.

Comment: Do large and complex programs still use that basic idea of just encrypting the I/O? Are there any other ways for a program to be compromised aside from just I/O? I'd eventually like to move into embedded programming, do you have any resources for security on embedded systems?

Comment: Well, that's a considerably broader question. There are a great number of possible ways to "compromise" a program aside from just I/O, just have a look at the update notes for any large program including the OS and browser you are using right now. And encryption doesn't necessarily help with compromise - a program can have full encryption of all I/O but still do something dumb with the data it loads into memory. Security of embedded systems has additional complications such as being difficult to update (consider applying an update to an oil well under the ocean or a satellite in orbit).